# Slick2D game - obstacle generation

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm working on a game (my first one!!) in which the player has to dodge asteroids and whatnot, and I can't figure out how I should go about generating the obstacles.  Is it wise (or even possible) to generate significantly-sized objects with a particle emitter?  Or is there a better solution?

I'm looking to have the obstacles (asteroids) flying in from various points off-screen at varying speeds and intervals.  I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations on starting development on your first game! Your question as asked is too broad for the format here at StackOverflow and will likely be closed as such. Please take some time to look through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the help center (particularly the topic of how to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). I look forward to seeing you join our community!

Comment: Please at least post solution you have thought about and if you have any problem implementing it then we can help